# Tagging Snapshots in Digitalocean

Tags: python, digital-ocean

I'm trying to tag a droplet snapshot in Digitalocean using python. Below is my code. I'm able to `request.get()` https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account just fine, but `request.put()` to https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/image/ doesn't seem to work. Digitalocean returns `HTTP 400`

```
        # This doesn't work
        url = "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/images/11111111"
        auth_header = "Bearer "+auth_token
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':auth_header}
        tag_array = ["wgm"]     
        data = {'tags':tag_array}
        resp = requests.put(url,headers=headers,data={'tags':tag_array})
        print(resp)

        # This works
        url = "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account"
        resp = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        print(resp)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can get an `HTTP 200` with curl, but the tag isn't updating. Is this even supported?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Turns out there is a way

You can use the Tags API to tag Droplet Snapshots – https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/tags_assign_resources. You'll need to set the `resource_type` to `image`:

Python example:

```
import os
from pydo import Client

client = Client(token=os.environ.get("DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN"))

req = {
  "resources": [
    {
      "resource_id": "7555620",
      "resource_type": "image"
    }
  ]
}

resp = client.tags.assign_resources(tag_id="My Custom Tag", body=req)
```

I created this [github issue](https://github.com/digitalocean/openapi/issues/854) to
bring the following points to the attention of the DigitalOcean team:

- There is no option to include tags in the request body when using the [`snapshot` action on a droplet](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/dropletActions_post)
- Tags do not seem to inherit from the droplet when snapshotting it
- It is not possible to edit snapshot tags (there are no `POST` actions, only [`GET` and `DELETE`](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#tag/Snapshots))

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to tag a droplet snapshot. That's not currently supported.

This doesn't seem possible at this time.

Comment: You should have made this a comment

Answer (score 0):

After you have created the snapshot, with the DO api You can tag a resource:
https://github.com/digitalocean/openapi/issues/854#issuecomment-1959841901